# json file (line delimited) on GCS incorrect when private - correct when public

Tags: json, authentication, encryption, google-cloud-storage, file-format

I am trying to load a json (newline delimited) file stored on a private GCS bucket using [ibis](https://ibis-project.org/). I get the following error:

`Invalid Input Error: Malformed JSON in file "<<<URL>>>", at byte 1 in record/value 2: unexpected character.`

However, after setting the file access to public I have no issues loading the data.

Makes me think GCS applies some kind of compression/encryption to private GCS files.

**Any idea how to get this issue solved is much appreciated!
**
Note that:
The url for private files starts with `https://storage.cloud.google.com`
The url for public files starts with `https://storage.googleapis.com`

Tried uploading the file with different file formats (.txt, .jsonl, .json) but no effect.

Also tried mingling the file type (application/json, text/plain) etc. No effect either.

The one thing I found to have effect is the access setting...

Comment: If the object is private (requires authorization), then the response is an HTML page with an error message. Confirm by looking at the response data.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley - thanks for your answer. The authorization was not the issue. I was using Ibis and with help of the community was able to relate the issue to the file specification. Forcing this to be 'gcs' (all in the python community, using 'fsspec' solved the issue.